# How do interfaces work internally in the Dart source code

Tags: dart, interface

If I create an interface in Dart like this:

```dart
abstract class MyType {
  factory MyType() => MyConcreteSubtype();
  void doSomthing();
}

class MyConcreteSubtype implements MyType {
  @override
  void doSomthing() {
    print(42);
  }
}
```

When I run the following code:

```dart
final myObject = MyType();
print(myObject.runtimeType); // MyConcreteSubtype
```

It prints `MyConcreteSubtype`.

Why is it then when I do this:

```dart
final myList = List();
print(myList.runtimeType); // List<dynamic>
```

It still says it's a `List`? The `List` source code is like this:

```dart
abstract class List<E> implements EfficientLengthIterable<E> {
  external factory List([int? length]);
  // ...
}
```

Besides the `external` keyword, how is that different than what I did? How is it that the runtime type of `List` still gets to pretend to be a `List` when my interface's runtime type is resolved to its concrete implementation type? And where is the concrete `List` implementation anyway? All I can find in the `dart:collections` library are the abstract classes `BaseList` and `ListMixin`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart allows classes to override the `runtimeType` getter.

Some internal platform-specific implementation types do so. For example, there are two or three different implementation classes implementing `int` in the VM platform libraries, but they all claim to have type `int`. You should never need to know the difference.

I'm guessing that you are running on the web. The JavaScript compiled code has the opposite issue: There are *zero* classes implementing the default `List`, instead it's represented directly by a JavaScript `Array`. So, there is no correct class that `[].runtimeType` can return a `Type` for, instead it just returns `List` itself. That's kind-of cheating, but it's also the nearest existing superclass of the actual (well, non-existing) implementation.

All in all, you should not trust `runtimeType` and you should not *use* `runtimeType` for anything except `dart:mirrors` (which doesn't exist on the web).

Comment: I'm testing the code in my question in VS Code running on a Mac.

Comment: So the Dart core libraries define interfaces and those interfaces are either interpreted by the VM or compiled to JavaScript or native code depending where the platform implements the Dart interfaces in its own way. Is that correct?

Comment: If I wanted to explore, say, how a VM platform library implements `int`, where would I look for that source code?

Comment: Correct. Look, for eaxmple, at https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/array.dart (VM list implementation) or https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/js_array.dart (dart2js list implementation - the one that it pretends JS Arrays implement).